# Change the representation of special characters in Gatling script

Tags: testing, gatling

How can I change the representation of special characters in Gatling? I need to do this in token exchange, for example:

Here is sample response from server

```
1a0
{"Url":"/signalr","ConnectionToken":"gZlor6itFi4JZqAXzTMmsyy/hWxivJg+BRLbTyUwjPhAJBHpf7f2AzOSlFEFuosoeSqMuwN/d7Fask/lrFTKxzFUHZC8ArveNyOb957Cqss18lNSmwiIFiHixGzzC3YAe5YwTdK0Uvb3WVEUvZ/V7g==","ConnectionId":"1fbdd61e-8186-4312-9a51-986d983e28d4","KeepAliveTimeout":20.0,"DisconnectTimeout":30.0,"ConnectionTimeout":110.0,"TryWebSockets":false,"ProtocolVersion":"1.5","TransportConnectTimeout":5.0,"LongPollDelay":0.0}
0
```

And token from it

```
gZlor6itFi4JZqAXzTMmsyy/hWxivJg+BRLbTyUwjPhAJBHpf7f2AzOSlFEFuosoeSqMuwN/d7Fask/lrFTKxzFUHZC8ArveNyOb957Cqss18lNSmwiIFiHixGzzC3YAe5YwTdK0Uvb3WVEUvZ/V7g==
```

Here is the request, which I captured via Fiddler from web app

```
GET /signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.5&Authorization=Bearer%20pVfF9mgAIu0Uylr9SFmQh3qA-TmG_fy8T60-f9C4bCFQYzTLbgvzNlBKknWZB_6T3ZaLa7z0bQBmvWILLDr_mXQHzlKr4EvGblzuIoeRrCm_vvL55tA0tDmtSoYhtA_mSxH27eG3jAYsXbDDQqqjmQUEtAQQhB6og_b8m2KQL211R14EXjkebDgiNoxkVKDqVKvatByveAq63RdOEzqd8QLNi72czK8SXtlfDttliSlKOYVypJvvdrhs0RmNM40VJBPZfZWd-Ew_I3cs8XKo9noynvWqm_yX7gDvDxNa_wP1lp3SkbExqlwuaJjtpvj3vKrfzTHm5iLLLCVrNZBOhwCjZiSQH_nrB17DG4_k7vWoJjDE3XX1W_ojuEjz3UNclhN28aRASWOJnoALW0Sr9JqRnQOoj8ncVKLnr-mQXr-XSsxNM1nBeUUihspocbjcvxlJYBiI81zzoyI4RKYeTaRKKjiJDvzq6EzFZ8wY3dnJPEKpSJXU7l0peTnHceld&connectionToken=gZlor6itFi4JZqAXzTMmsyy%2FhWxivJg%2BBRLbTyUwjPhAJBHpf7f2AzOSlFEFuosoeSqMuwN%2Fd7Fask%2FlrFTKxzFUHZC8ArveNyOb957Cqss18lNSmwiIFiHixGzzC3YAe5YwTdK0Uvb3WVEUvZ%2FV7g%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22livechat%22%7D%5D&tid=10 HTTP/1.1
```

And the token

```
gZlor6itFi4JZqAXzTMmsyy%2FhWxivJg%2BBRLbTyUwjPhAJBHpf7f2AzOSlFEFuosoeSqMuwN%2Fd7Fask%2FlrFTKxzFUHZC8ArveNyOb957Cqss18lNSmwiIFiHixGzzC3YAe5YwTdK0Uvb3WVEUvZ%2FV7g%3D%3D
```

But when I extract all tokens and use them in Gatling, I have tokens with special characters, like here

```
gZlor6itFi4JZqAXzTMmsyy/hWxivJg+BRLbTyUwjPhAJBHpf7f2AzOSlFEFuosoeSqMuwN/d7Fask/lrFTKxzFUHZC8ArveNyOb957Cqss18lNSmwiIFiHixGzzC3YAe5YwTdK0Uvb3WVEUvZ/V7g==
```

And server responds with 400 error. My question is, how can I change the representation of this characters? Below my script, if additional info is required, let me know.

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._

class logingood extends Simulation {

    val httpProtocol = http
        .baseUrl("https://webapi.wage.iteodev.com")
        .inferHtmlResources()
        .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36")
        .proxy(Proxy("localhost", 8888).httpsPort(8888))

    val headers_0 = Map(
        "Accept" -> "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Origin" -> "https://frontend.iteodev.com",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode" -> "cors")

    val headers_1 = Map(
        "Access-Control-Request-Headers" -> "authorization",
        "Access-Control-Request-Method" -> "GET",
        "Origin" -> "https://frontend.iteodev.com",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode" -> "cors")

    val headers_2 = Map(
        "Accept" -> "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Origin" -> "https://frontend.iteodev.com",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode" -> "cors",
        "authorization" -> "Bearer ${authToken}")


    val headers_3 = Map("Sec-Fetch-Mode" -> "no-cors")

    val headers_7 = Map(
        "Origin" -> "https://frontend.iteodev.com",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode" -> "cors",
        "content-type" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")

    val uri1 = "https://api.wage.iteodev.com/signalr"
    val uri2 = "https://frontend.iteodev.com/static/media/download-app-headline.a2c2b312.svg"

    val scn = scenario("logingood")
        .exec(http("request_0")
            .post("/api/oauth/token")
            .headers(headers_0)
            .formParam("username", "test@evxmail.net")
            .formParam("password", "Zaq1@wsx")
            .formParam("grant_type", "password")
            .check(jsonPath("$..access_token").exists.saveAs("authToken"))
            .resources(http("request_1")
            .options("/api/account")
            .headers(headers_1),
            http("request_2")
            .get("/api/account")
            .headers(headers_2),
            http("request_3")
            .get(uri2)
            .headers(headers_3),
            http("request_4")
            .options("/api/conversations/")
            .headers(headers_1),
            http("request_5")
            .get("/api/conversations/")
            .headers(headers_2),
            http("request_6")
            .options("/api/notifications")
            .headers(headers_1)))

        .exec(
        exec(http("request_7")
        .get(uri1 + "/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&Authorization=Bearer%20${authToken}&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22livechat%22%7D%5D")
        .check(regex("""[a-zA-Z0-9=\/+]{152}""").find.saveAs("MyConnectionToken"))
        .headers(headers_7)),
        exec(http("request_8")
        .get("/api/notifications")
        .headers(headers_2)),
        exec(http("request_9")
        .get(uri1 + "/start?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.5&Authorization=Bearer%20${authToken}&connectionToken=${MyConnectionToken}&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22livechat%22%7D%5D")
        .headers(headers_7))
        exec(http("request_10")
        .get(uri1 + "/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.5&Authorization=Bearer%20${authToken}&connectionToken=${MyConnectionToken}&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22livechat%22%7D%5D")
        .headers(headers_7))
        exec(http("request_9")
        .get(uri1 + "/start?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.5&Authorization=Bearer%20${authToken}&connectionToken=${MyConnectionToken}&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22livechat%22%7D%5D")
        .headers(headers_7)))


    setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `disableUrlEncoding`?

It should be the method you are looking for : [Gatling official docs: URL encoding](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_request/#url-encoding)

There is an example here in this Github issue: [Doc: non-existing method disableUrlEncoding](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/2497), which is fixed by now